# Code for passing user information from azureAD to app.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am trying to introduce the Single-Sign-On (SSO) feature to my React app and I want to use the user information from my company for the SSO verification. For that, I registered my application on the Azure website to acquire the clientID. I have found an article that shows how to make use of React AAD MSAL package to enable user login through a popup method: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aad-msal .
I create an authProvider.js file with the following code:

```
// authProvider.js
import { MsalAuthProvider, LoginType } from 'react-aad-msal';
 
// Msal Configurations
const config = {
  auth: {
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common',
    clientId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    redirectUri: 'localhost:3000'
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "localStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true
  }
};
 
// Authentication Parameters
const authenticationParameters = {
  scopes: [
    'User.Read'
  ]
}
 
// Options
const options = {
  loginType: LoginType.Popup,
  tokenRefreshUri: window.location.origin + '/auth.html'
}
 
export const authProvider = new MsalAuthProvider(config, authenticationParameters, options)
```

and my index.js file looks like this:

```
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AzureAD } from 'react-aad-msal';
 
import App from './App';
import { authProvider } from './authProvider';
 
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <AzureAD provider={authProvider} forceLogin={true}>
      <App />
    </AzureAD>
  <BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

This code worked and allowed me to authenticate users on the sign in and then redirected them to the redirect URL. I now would like to pass user information such as name, surname, email address and profile picture to the `App` component.

I was not able to find resources online that would help me do it and the documentation on the npm website does not have examples of that being done. Could anyone provide working code examples of how to do what I want? (All my files are in js and I can not use any code examples provided by Microsoft as they use tsx files and I don't want to change all my files to TypeScript).

Perhaps there are some children or property functions in `MsalAuthProvider` that I can call but I could not find documentation on that function either. I am also not sure of where to call these functions in index.js so code examples would be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could get user information with `myMSALObj.getAccount()` using MSAL.js.

```
const myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

function signIn() {
  myMSALObj.loginPopup(loginRequest)
    .then(loginResponse => {
      console.log('id_token acquired at: ' + new Date().toString());
      console.log(loginResponse);

      if (myMSALObj.getAccount()) {
        showWelcomeMessage(myMSALObj.getAccount());
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

For more details about the code sample, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa).

---

Also you could get access token in your code with `react-aad-msal`. Some information of the user such as username and email will be shown after decoding the token.

```
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
const claims = jwtDecode('base64 encoded token received from Azure AD');
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as an answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work